# Page fixed at a specific post in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity A. From that activity I go to activity B. Now there are some image descriptions in A and the corresponding images are in B. I want to make a system where based on the descriptions from activity A, the screen gets fixed to the post with the specific image among all the posts when I move from A to B.  In other words I want to fix recyclerview to a specific child when the activity B opens.
P.S.- I have the postkeys of all the posts in recyclerview in B in my database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you facing? and what did you do so far?

Comment: I actually don't have a clue how to do it. If I only use intent, it will go the first post in the recyclerview in B. I have passed the postkey of the specific post from A to B. Now I want to set the recyclerview to the exact post with the postkey

Comment: I'm not if I understood you correctly, when you pass postKey from A to B, get the items from your database related to that passed postKey and set it to your recyclerview.
Or do you want any specific row to be focused/Selected?

Comment: I want a specific row to be focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the row position associated to your postKey from your activity B `recyclerViewAdapter` then auto scroll to that postion

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(rowPosition); //if you want a smooth scroll
```

or

```
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(rowPosition);
```